# PDO mock object missing getConnection

Tags: php, unit-testing, pdo

after mocking PDO object like this:

```
class AdProvidersTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function dataProvider()
    {
        $providers =  array (
            array (1, '1st', 'desc_1', 101),
            array (2, '2nd', 'desc_2', 202),
            array (3, '3rd', 'desc_3', 303)
          );

        return $providers;
    }
    /**
     * @dataProvider dataProvider
     */
    public function testAdProviders_getConnection($id, $name, $desc, $account_id)
    {
        $data = array (
            array (
                'id' => $id,
                'name' => $name,
                'desc' => $desc,
                'account_id' => $account_id,
            )
        );

        $stmt = $this->getMock('PDOStatement', array ('execute','fetchAll'));
        $stmt->expects($this->any())
             ->method('execute')
             ->will($this->returnValue(true));
        $stmt->expects($this->any())
             ->method('fetchAll')
             ->will($this->returnValue($data));

        $pdo = $this->getMock('PDO', array('prepare'),
            array('sqlite:dbname=:memory'),'PDOMock_' . uniqid(),true);
        $pdo->expects($this->any())
            ->method('prepare')
            ->will($this->returnValue($stmt));


    }
}
```

i want to test the connection using this function:

```
      function getDbh() 
      {
        if ($this->db === null){
          $this->db = Slim::getInstance()->db;
        }
        return $this->db->getConnection();
      }
```

but after setting up the database using the pdo mock i get this error when trying to get the connection:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method AdProvidersTest::getMockConnection() in /home/al/adserver/adserver/test/classes/AdProvidersTest.php on line 48
```

is there a way to add this `getConnection` function to the mocked PDO?

Comment: When is `getMockConnections()` being called?  The method simply does not exist but I do not see anywhere in your code when it is called.  Have you included all of the source code here?

Comment: `getMockConnections()`?? i looked and couldn't find any documentation about it, can you please explain or reference? i was talking about `getConnection()` inside `getDbh()`

Comment: If you read the error you will see that it cant find a method you are attempting to call.  So I suppose you need to create that method.  On the other hand, I do not even see were it is being called from.  I am unfamiliar with the classes/API you are using, maybe you need to look closer at their docs

Comment: Probably need to rename "testAdProviders_getConnection" as "getMockConnections" but as others say: need more code; it's not standard so please post the rest of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message states that line 48 in `AdProvidersTest.php` is calling the method `getMockConnection()` in the `class AdProvidersTest` and that *you have not defined the method* `getMockConnection()` in `class AdProvidersTest`

Does this help you narrow in on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Look method getMock() inside it must call getMockConnection().